# .htaccess getting internet server error

Tags: .htaccess

i have following code:

```
RewriteRule ^(feedback|contact)/? /contact-us\.php?ct=$1 [L]
```

which is returning **INTERNET SERVER ERROR** , Why?

But when i remove `|contact` , it works.

Working code:

```
RewriteRule ^(feedback)/? /contact-us\.php?ct=$1 [L]
```

Why it works, and earlier doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is causing infinite loop (code 500) for a URI like: `/contact/` because you're matching following regex in your RewriteRule:

```
^(feedback|contact)/?
```

And then you're internally forwarding matched URI to:

```
/contact-us.php?ct=contact
```

Which you can see will again match your regex: `^(feedback|contact)/?` and your rule will again redirect to `/contact-us.php?ct=contact`. This matching & forwarding will continue until Rewrite Limit is reached and Apache throws an error.

**To avoid this looping you should use following rule:**

```
RewriteRule ^(feedback|contact)(/.*|)$ /contact-us.php?ct=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Above rule will match following URIs:

```
/contact
/contact/
/contact/foo
/contact/foo/bar
...
```

But it **will NOT match** URI: `/contact-us.php` thus preventing the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
^(feedback|contact).*? /contact-us\.php?ct=$1 [L]
```

Which will match the two choices.